# Why system variable (path) wasn't created after jdk 1.7 installed

Tags: java

All, It was the the first time I met this kind of problem, When I installed the jdk 1.7, there is no problem found in this process. After that , I try to verify the version of the jdk . so I run the `java` command in the dos window. But got the result says `java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Can anybody tell me why and what happen? thanks.

Comment: you have to set manually JAVA_HOME=jdk7_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java installer does not automatically add the `bin` directory of the JDK to the `PATH`, as you seem to expect.

You'll have to do that yourself, as is explained in the JDK installation instructions:

[Updating the PATH Environment Variable (Optional)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path)

Comment: Seems the jdk 1.5(1.6) can create this system variable automatically, So I wonder why it doesn't work for jdk 1.7..

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Path variable under Start -> System to the bin folder of your java installation if you are working under Windows